# Why does changing aperture change field of view in my reverse-lens macro setup?

Tags: aperture, field-of-view, reversed-lens

I have a reverse lens macro setup, with a reversed 35 mm lens attached through an adapter to a 80-200 zoom lens. I have the following issue: changing the aperture setting on the zoom lens changes the field of view in my system.

I’m not sure why the aperture ring is changing the field stop. Can anyone help explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mechanical vignetting. The aperture of the rear lens should be wide open and you adjust the aperture of the front lens.

See here for more: http://www.coinimaging.com/coupled_lenses.html